# Neo4j Hamiltonian path (TSP)

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Being a newbie with graphs, I'm looking whether it's possible to use Neo4j to calculate an optimal route which passes through all entered waypoints (distances are weights of the edges).

I'm familiar with ability to use A* and Dijkstra to find shortest/cheapest paths, but haven't found an easy way to do this. Since the number of nodes for each calculation will be relatively small (< 30), I'm primarily hoping for ease of implementation with Neo4j (if possible) compared to coding the solution from scratch in Node.js, since I guess performance won't be a problem at this scale.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

for this you must take a look into gremling traversal language, which neo4j aslo implements. pure cypher core wont be of any help.